# How to save a file with password in UFT

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft, uft14

I am using UFT 12.5. During run time it opens excel and word. Then it writes some data in the both files. After that, I would like to save both files with a new name and then password protected. I need to be able to enter password manually to open it. So far, I have written the below code and I getting an error at the last line.

```
Set ExcelObj = createobject("excel.application")
ExcelObj.Visible = true

Set ExcelFile = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open (file)
Set ScripSheet = ExcelFile.Worksheets("Scripts")
ScripSheet.Cells(1,1) = "Passed"
ExcelFile.SaveAs mm1, "ttt"
```

Please advise on how I can save word and excel files with a password using UFT.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass correct parameters with **`SaveAs`** method. Check [**`this`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saveas-method-excel) link for more info.
Here is the working code that you can try:

```
file = "File path with file name"
newfile = "File path with new file name"

Set ExcelObj = createobject("excel.application")
ExcelObj.Visible = true

Set ExcelFile = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open (file)
Set ScripSheet = ExcelFile.Worksheets("Scripts")
ScripSheet.Cells(1,1) = "Passed"
ExcelFile.SaveAs newfile, , "test"
ExcelFile.Close
ExcelObj.Quit
```

**UPDATE**
Per comments from OP

If you want to save file with **`ReadOnly`**, you have to use **`WriteResPassword`** parameter this way:

```
ExcelFile.SaveAs newfile, , , "test"
```

> Note that I've two empty parameters for **`FileFormat`** and
> **`Password`** respectively.
>
> **This way it will ask for password to open the file in write mode and if you won't provide the password, file will be opened in `ReadOnly`
> mode.**

Check the link that I've mentioned.

Comment: Now, it requires the password to view it. Anyone can view the file without the password. Password is needed only when they try to edit the file. Can we do that?  Sorry if I was not clear on my post.

Comment: Search for **`worksheet locked for editing`** on Google, you'll get tons of answers.

Comment: I need to do that using UFT. I searched. It does not provide the solution using UFT. It provides how to do it manually.